# Add data between HTML tags to PHP array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, transformation

Suppose I have a PHP variable that is a bunch of data in tags. Something like this:

```
$target_element = '<td colspan="3"> Data Header 1 </td> 
                   //colspan can not be changed to something like class or id.
                           <td class="data_title"> Title1_1 </td>
                           <td class="data_item"> Data1_1 </td>


                           <td class="data_title"> Title1_2 </td>
                           <td class="data_item"> Data1_2 </td>


                           <td class="data_title"> Title1_3 </td>
                           <td class="data_item"> Data1_3 </td>



                           <td colspan="3"> Data Header 2 </td>

                           <td class="data_title"> Title2_1 </td>
                           <td class="data_item"> Data2_1 </td>


                           <td class="data_title"> Title2_2 </td>
                           <td class="data_item"> Data2_2 </td>';
```

What is the best way to change the above into a PHP Array that looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Data Header 1
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Title1_1
                    [1] => Data1_1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Title1_2
                    [1] => Data1_2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Title1_3
                    [1] => Data1_3
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Data Header 2
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Title2_1
                    [1] => Data2_1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Title2_2
                    [1] => Data2_2
                )

        )

)
```

Notice the titles/data in each can vary.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In a general way, possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: You could use a foreach.